# What determines the order CSS is "specified" between two elements when loaded from different files?

Tags: css, browser, css-specificity, css-cascade

I'm helping to debug a CSS issue where two identical selectors are loading in a different order between two identically configured servers. One rule gets loaded from a stylesheet defined in the page and another gets loaded by Javascript injecting the stylesheet file.

According to the cascade rules, as I read them, it should come down to the order in which the rules are specified. It appears as though the issue is a race condition, but it's not clear what the basis for the race condition is. In Chrome's network tab, the files are listed in the same order between the two servers; however, when you drill down to the element level in the Elements tab, the rule taking precedence on a given server is listed first.

What determines the order in which the CSS is "specified" between two elements when loaded like this?

Comment: When does the javascript start executing? when the page is fully loaded or inline? Please provide a small sample of the code where the CSS and JS parts are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selectors are identical, it comes down to order... order within the CSS and the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). So, the question is, where did you place the dynamically generated `<link>` (or `<style>`) in relation to the original `<link>` (or `<style>`)? The order within the DOM matters.

If you'd like to make sure that your dynamically created CSS gets evaluated first, add it to the top of the `<head>`:

```
document.head.insertBefore(myLink, document.head.firstChild);
```

If you'd like it to be evaluated last, append it to the `<body>`:

```
document.body.appendChild(myLink);
```

Whichever rule is evaluated last will be the one applied (barring use of `!important`)

Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      p {
        color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>test</p>  
    <script>
      (function() {

        var red = document.createElement("style");
        red.textContent = "p { color: red }";
        // We'll add this to the top of head. You'll never even notice because it will
        // be overridden by the existing green style.
        document.head.insertBefore(red, document.head.firstChild);

        var blue = document.createElement("style");
        blue.textContent = "p { color: blue }";
        // We'll add this to the end of the body after a three second delay. It will 
        // override the other styles.
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.body.appendChild(blue);
        }, 3000);

      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked the Elements tab in Chrome and the order in which the <link> tag appears for each of the CSS files is different between the two servers. The next step will be determining why. The dynamically loaded file is getting added via Modernizr.load, so I'm guessing that comes into play somehow.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is a selector strength.

If I use a schema, it's:
`inline > identifier (100) > class (10) > tag (1)` - you can count 'points' in brackets to find the selector strength.

You know that, probably.

Now, when you have two selectors of the same strength, which are applied to one element, eg.

```
#main p {color: red}
#top p {color: green}
```

and HTML

```
<div id=main>
    <div id=top>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Paragraph will be green and in dev tools red color will be striked. Both selectors has the same strength, the latest wins.

Other example is:

```
#main #top p {color: red} /* will be red, stronger selector */
#main p {color: green}
```

In HTML the main factor is the order in which are styles linked to document, and order of rules (directly in HTML or in CSS). Doesn't matter which CSS file is loaded first (eg. due to file size), the position in HTML document is important.

Comment: According to the OP, he's dealing with _"two identical selectors."_ That makes the only relevant part of your answer the last paragraph... which was (suspiciously?) added after my answer.

Comment: @canon: not sure if before or after, i wanted to write more about, take it a little bit wider how the rules are applied. I didnt read your answer, just have idea to fill it Into my answer, you have the samé in the same time :-)